# Newbie Objective C Error such as _main

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I've been tinkering all day, and I can't seem to fix this error.

Here's the code:

```
//
//  main.m
//  Learning ObjC
//
//  Created by Nickirv on 8/9/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Nickirv. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person: NSObject{
    int age;
    int weight;
}
-(void) print;
-(void) setAge: (int) a;
-(void) SetWeight: (int) w;
@end
```

And it outputs this issue:

```
 "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

Comment: A leading underscore `_` is prepended to function names by the compiler so the `main` you see becomes `_main` to the compiler and in error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete the `main` boilerplate code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the end Objective-C is "C" and the program starts execution by calling `main`. Additionally Objective-C code needs to execute in an `autoreleasepool`.

You define class `@interfaces` and `@implemtations` outside of (generally above) the boilerplate but the first line of code to run must be within the autoreleasepool scope `{}`.

Here is an example Objective-C program similar to what the OP seems to want using `@properties` for simplicity and demonstration.

It is important to study Objective-C documentation until the following code is fully understood, td;dr does not work for this.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person: NSObject
@property int age;
@property int weight;
- (void)print;
@end

@implementation Person : NSObject
- (void)print {
    printf("Age: %i, weight: %i", self.age, self.weight);
}
@end


 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        Person *don = [[Person alloc] init];
        don.weight = 130;
        don.age = 23;
        [don print];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Age: 23, weight: 130

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would it matter if the main boilerplate code is above my @implementation and @interfaces?

Comment: Yes it would in this case because the `main` function must know about what it calls. In general in Objective-C classes there does not need to be a prior declaration (order of methods) in the current compilers. The difference is kind a quirk in the compiler. In general the Objective-C code is in a separate file so this ordering issue is not a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sincere help!